# Find the total number of rentals for each genre

Tags: mysql

The following are the tables in the database (removed irrelevant tables). I want to query for the total count of rentals for each genre. Note that a movie can have multiple genres.

```
MOVIE:  Table of movies that are available in the video store.
    id:             Integer identifying the movie instance.
    title:          String with the title of the movie.
    duration:       Integer with the total duration of the movie, in seconds.
    release_year:   Integer with the year of release of the movie.
    rental_rate:    Float with the daily cost of renting the movie.
    rating:         Float in the interval 0-10, measuring how much viewers 
                    enjoyed the movie.

GENRE:  Table of movie genres.
    id:             Integer identifying the genre instance.
    name:           String with the name of the genre.

RENTAL:  Table of video rentals.
    id:             Integer identifying the rental instance.
    customer_id:    Integer identifying the customer who performed the rental.
    movie_id:       Integer identifying the movie that was rented.
    checkout_date:  Integer with unix timestamp, in seconds, marking when 
                    the video was checked out by the customer.
    return_date:    Integer with unix timestamp, in seconds, marking when the 
                    video was returned by the customer.
    cost:           Float with total dollar amount that was charged to the 
                    customer for the rental.

MOVIE_GENRE:  Association between a movie and its genre.
    movie_id:       Integer identifying the movie instance.
    genre_id:       Integer identifying the genre instance.
```

What I have managed to do is simply count all the movies in each genre.

```
SELECT COUNT(mg.genre_id) AS movieCount, g.name
  FROM MOVIE_GENRE mg, GENRE g
  WHERE mg.genre_id = g.id
  GROUP BY mg.genre_id;
```

I'm doubting that this query even helps in what I'm trying to do. I know how I can achieve this programmatically, but I'm not sure how to express it in SQL.
We need to map each rental to a movie then to its genres, and count the genres we find here. How do I express this in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

I've reduced a bit your table schema:

```
create table movie 
(
    id int primary key, 
    title varchar(20)
);

create table genre
(
    id int primary key, 
    name varchar(20)
);

create table movie_genre
(
    movie_id int, 
    genre_id int,
    primary key (movie_id, genre_id),
    foreign key (movie_id) references movie (id),
    foreign key (genre_id) references genre (id)
);

create table rental 
(
    id int primary key, 
    movie_id int
);
```

And then insert some values:

```
insert into movie values 
(1, 'movie 1'), (2, 'movie 2'), (3, 'movie 3'), (4, 'movie 4');

insert into genre values 
(1, 'genre 1'), (2, 'genre 2'), (3, 'genre 3'), (4, 'genre 4');

insert into movie_genre values
(1, 2), (1, 3),
(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4),
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4),
(4, 2);

insert into rental values
(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 1), (6, 3), (7, 4);
```

Now joining all tables and grouping by `genre.name` you can get the count of each genre:

```
select   g.name, count(*) rentals
from     rental r
join     movie  m
on       r.movie_id = m.id
join     movie_genre mg
on       mg.movie_id = m.id
join     genre g
on       mg.genre_id = g.id
group by g.name;
```

> ```
> name    | rentals
> :------ | ------:
> genre 1 |       3
> genre 2 |       7
> genre 3 |       5
> genre 4 |       3
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=863d297f58408de1eba06f25265f7c24)*</kbd>

Comment: `g.id` is better for grouping than `g.name`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(g.id) AS movieCount, g.name
  FROM rental r, movie m, movie_genre mg, genre g
  WHERE r.movie_id = m.id AND m.id = mg.movie_id AND mg.genre_id = g.id
  GROUP BY g.id
  HAVING movieCount >= 20
  ORDER BY movieCount DESC;
```

Comment: You have to use `JOIN..ON` instead of `JOIN..WHERE`. Your approach generate the product size of `r * m * mg * g` while `JOIN..ON`'s product is not bigger than `r`

Comment: @Kondybas, while explicit ansi join is preferred over the older "," join you dont *have* to use it. You can filter in the where clause instead and let the optimizer decide how to evaluate the query. How do you conclude that the JOIN is not bigger than r? For example if a movie belongs to several genres, the cardinality of the join may be bigger than r.

Comment: Yep, product is not bigger than `r*g`

Comment: Optimizer can't do all the job. Straight explicit syntax even with `USE INDEX FOR JOIN` is preferrable in most cases.